# bulkloader Listproperty utf8

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I got a problem stuck me few days,  tried several ways still can't figure it out.

it's about data upload using csv file in utf-8

here is main.Py

```
class hello(db.Model):
    greeting = db.StringListProperty()  (or Listproperty(unicode))

class dbLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self,'hello',
        [
        ('greeting', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8').split('|'))
        ])
loaders = [dbLoader]
```

the data.cv contains:

"Hello|您好|こんにちは|¡Hola|مرحبا|안녕하세요"

stored entity just like
[u'Hello', u'\u60a8\u597d', u'\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f', u'\xa1Hola', u'\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627', u'\uc548\ub155\ud558\uc138\uc694']
character isn't correct.

Any further for me ... appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is being imported correctly. The stored entity is simply being displayed in Python's `repr` format, which represents unicode strings with characters outside the first 127 as unicode codepoints. Taking your second field, we get the same result with regular Python on the command line:

```
$ echo 您好 | python -c "import sys; print repr(sys.stdin.read().decode('utf8'))"
u'\u60a8\u597d\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick, even composing my question clear. a lots thanks ;)